# merge multiple .txt file

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I have .txt 37 files in a folder. I want to combine them all together using vba code. I also want to add name of the file as file_name column in the beginning. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks .

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code which shows you have made some effort and you will get help.

Comment: This would be much easier with Power Query than with VBA

Comment: Please share some samples of source files content, and expected output for them.